How to format References/citations for a non-English language?
I have three questions about formatting references/citations in a non-English language under the NATBIB package (I am using polyglossia.sty package), one is related to the numbering mode and the other two are related to the author-year mode as follows:
(1) Numbering mode: how references and citations can be numbered using non-English numerals?
(2) Author-year mode in citation: How "and" can be replaced with another word in case of a two-author reference and "et al." can be changed with another?
(3) Author-year mode in citation: How "et al." can be replaced with another word in case of a more than two-author reference?

Can you add some background information if you have to use natbib because you are writing an article for a journal or do you have the freedom to switch to another bibliography tool like biblatex? The later is often easier to customise. Maybe also mention which language you want to use.
